# Find & replace using regex for input to Google Sheet

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a dataset:

```
1.  
Name1  
Name2  
Name3  
2.  
Name1  
Name2.  
Name3
```

and so on.

Using regex, I want the output to be:

```
Name1,Name2,Name3  
Name1,Name2.,Name3
```

I'm trying to import into a google sheet, so need a comma delimited file.  I believe that the steps are to replace the numbers followed by a period with `\n` and then add a comma after each column name.  Note that some fields Ex: `Name2.` have a number followed by a period so having issues with `\d+[.]`

Comment: Is it a typo or you want to remove the dot?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60657569/edit) and add real text and expected result.

Comment: Are there **always** 3 lines that you want to join?

Comment: Name2. is to show that there may be some data with a dot (not a typo) so need to account for that.  I don't want to replace, but to account for it when searching/replacing.

Comment: Yes there are always 3 lines that need to be joined.

Comment: @getyourbiglobster Your expected output does not align with that comment you just made... Shouldn't line 2 have a dot after "Name2" in that case?

Comment: In your expected result,, the dot efter `Name2.` is removed. What do you really want to do? I repeat my demand: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60657569/edit) and add real text and expected result.

Comment: And, please, format properly.

Comment: Apologies.  I've formatted accordingly and yes, line 2 should have a dot after Name2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)\R(.+)\R(.+)$`
- Replace with: `$1,$2,$3`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   # beginning of line
    (.+)            # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
    \R              # any kind of  linebreak
    (.+)            # group 2, 1 or more any character but newline
    \R              # any kind of  linebreak
    (.+)            # group 3, 1 or more any character but newline
$
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1
,           # comma
$2          # content of group 2
,           # comma
$3          # content of group 3
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  And if I were to add more fields to my data set, would i just add another '(.+)\R' in find and a '$#' in replace?  Assuming so.

Comment: @getyourbiglobster: Yes, you're right, add as many goups as needed. If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: So, several hundred records in and I now see that the number of items that I want to join won't be consistent.  This worked with 3, 13 and any consistent number of items, but I now see it varies.  Any thoughts on how to account for this?

Comment: @getyourbiglobster: This is a bit different question, how do you know the lines to be joined and the other?. Please, ask a new one with some **real** lines and expected result